# Congratulations, Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair is graduated!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day, Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

Graduation works in two phases. To expand what's happening today.

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - not scheduled yet but it'll either be mid-October or early November.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name. This is already active.
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network. This is already active.
- You will be able to select your own community ads. These will be going up today.
- For the second phase, the site will at a later date receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. This will be preceded by the designer pitching their ideas and soliciting feedback from the community.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Thank you for the announcement ... we *really* appreciate it!

Comment: Oh man. There goes our chance at the longest beta ever award, we'll have to settle for #8. Can't wait to see the site theme.

Comment: @Grace - as it has been a wee bit of time with no further update, I thought it would be appropriate to get the community thinking about site design: http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1875/37

Answer (score 26):

Wow ... Just ***WOW!***

We have been waiting for this for a long time ... I've been here every day for almost three years (yes *every day*). I've longed to see us graduated. Through the thin times and the thick times. What an awesome journey. Now, we finally get this monkey off our back ... the monkey called *Beta*. I know for the last little while we we've had no worries about getting shut down, but still, we can now say we are over that hump. Awesome Sauce. :o)

I, too, want to thanks to a few people who have made Mechanics.SE what it is today:

- @BobCross : Thanks for being here as a Mod. You truly encapsulate the meaning of the term. This place would not be the same without you!
- @Movemorecommentslinktotop (Larry): I know you've been through some crap over the past year, but you've kept with us and helped keep the site running. It is appreciated!
- @DucatiKiller (Paul): Thank you sir, for pulling this place together this past December (2015). Between you and Zaid, this place really started popping. I might be able to say I helped this place survive, but you and Zaid got us on track and graduated.
- @Zaid : What can I say? You are just awesome my friend. If the above comments don't give you a big head, I don't know what will. Thanks for getting us here.
- @RoryAlsop : You Motorhead, Guitar Picking, Rocking the Kasbah kinda guy! Your mechanical knowhow and enthusiasm has helped us get over the top. Thanks for sticking by and helping this happen!

Now on to bigger and better things!

Special thanks to some of our members who have helped so much in getting us here:

@NickC @mikes @vini_i @BrianKnoblauch @SteveMatthews @JPhi1618 @FredWilson @HandyHowie @JuannStrauss @cdunn @rpmerf @ShobinP @Ben @RobertS.Barnes @SteveRacer @Moab @dlu @MaxGoodridge @MooseLucifer @sweber @MarkJohnson @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing @Nick @JonathanMusso @JasonC @racefever @Pete @hillsons @cloudynyn @amphibient @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ @chilljeet @LynnCrumbling @resident_heretic @PoissonFish @Nick @Myself @Autistic @Edward @DavidWinslow @cnst @DavidLively  ... and the list goes on! (I know I didn't include a lot of people here who should be mentioned, but please do not feel slighted ... you all put a lot of time and effort into things. It is more than appreciated.

I hope to see all of you putting even more effort into making this place even better than it is now. I'm just way too excited for words (though you couldn't tell it by this writ!)

Oh, and one last thank you:

Thanks to @JonEricson for showing us what we needed to do to get here. Your Meta post was just what we needed. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Indeed Bro.  There's not much else to say.  Everyone contributed to the success and that in itself is simply amazing.  Great community here, can't wait to see what the 'next level' is.

Comment: Agreed - we have a great community here, with so many regular contributors. It's great to see it without hte 'beta' tag...

Comment: Man, I wish I still had as much time as I used to, I could have made it in the first section of thanks!  This is exciting stuff except for all the privileges that I will loose.  And big thanks to you too Paulster!

Answer (score 18):

Congrats to all hands!  I can't believe we've been working on the site for over five years now.  It's been a long road but everyone should be proud.

Hooray!

Comment: Thanks for all commitment and cajoling.  Your mod style has been next level.  Proud to be a small part of it.  Congratulations!!!

Comment: Woohoo!!  Graduation.  Can't wait to see the site design!

Comment: @JPhi1618, hey, I remember you!  ;-)

Answer (score 16):

### I don't know where to begin...

*There's just so much I want to say!*

---

### Graduation means:

- that there's finally a full-fledged alternative to the (almost) ubiquitous, often opinionated forum banter that vehicle owners have to endure when they seek answers to questions that matter to them.
- an official recognition by Stack Exchange of the valuable contributions by the diaspora of individuals that form our community.
- a personal accomplishment for a goal I had set myself a few years ago; I wanted to build a vehicle-agnostic site that could cater for newbies and experts alike while maintaining a high signal-to-noise ratio.

---

### Those who deserve special mention

There are so many people who deserve to be on this list, but if I had to limit myself to a handful of people:

- ***@Bob Cross*** and ***@Movemorecommentslinktotop***, for continuing to moderate the site for 4+ years despite their busy schedules, above and beyond their call of duty.
- ***@Paulster2***, for investing so much time and knowledge into the site and holding out the fort for so long.
- ***@DucatiKiller***, for his help in shaping and executing a focused strategy to ensure that we met all requirements for SE graduation.

---

### A moment to reflect on what we've created

For me, we didn't just build an SE site. We built:

- a beacon of light for those who are not so mechanically-inclined
- a watering hole for gearheads from all walks of life
- a remarkable SE chat room, [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop)
- a world-class knowledge repository for all things that go vroom

All in all,

### Congratulations!

Comment: Well said my friend.

Comment: Wow ... I could not have said it better myself ... but you know me ... I gotta say something! So well said ... yes indeed. And thank you for the kind compliment, not only for myself, but for Bob, Larry, and Paul (Ducati) as well.

Comment: ......and.....You're the man!

Comment: Been waiting so long for this.. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Awesome! I got up this morning and all sorts of exciting had happened!

Took a little longer than hoped, but I think that gave a chance for everyone to develop the site scope further through discussion, improve the welcome to new folks through the FAQs, and spread the good word through the HNQ list.

Graduation is the reward for all you folks' hard work! You really really know your stuff.

I'm happy being a part of this community, but am very much an amateur mechanic (very interested, but not enough time to really be good at it) so I'm glad I can help from the perspective of knowing how SE works. But I am in awe of how much you folks actually know about engines, and how amazingly helpful you are in sharing that knowledge.

Mechanics is going to go from strength to strength! Congratulations to all!

I really can't wait to see the site design and logo...(and did anyone mention site graduation swag?)

Comment: Thanks for all the help you've given EVERYONE in the community regarding sifting through meta and answering some of our rudimentary questions.  You've helped me out a lot, and now, I hope you know that.   Cheers to you and the community!

Answer (score 8):

**Huge congratulations!**

I'm so happy for you! This is such a great community! Your diligence in growing this community is an example to others. Through years of hard work, perseverance, and waiting, you're getting the recognition and respect a graduated site deserves. I thank all of you whose names have been mentioned, as well as those who haven't.

My opinions are the same as all the others, but I'll add them anyway!

You people do so many things well, it's impossible to narrow it down, but the things that stick out to me most:

**Care for your community**

This site is more like a family than a community, and there is a genuine caring for those who come. That's a rare thing in life in general, and especially on the internet, where people are frequently mean, or apathetic. 
You can't fake that type of devotion, and it extends to all, without regard for their level of experience, language or country of origin, or "quality" of questions and answers.

The SE system is much different than what most people are used to, and it's hard to learn. Rather than sending people back to a more comfortable, but lower quality, place, you all pitch in to help. Users aren't left hanging, and you give great personal attention to the posts. You also empower people by voting so they get the rep they need to do things on the site, and give them the ability to participate more and have fun, which translates into longtime users who tell their friends. You think carefully before closing questions, especially for new users, and when you have to do it, you still leave friendly and encouraging comments.

Even users from other SE sites are treated exceptionally well here, and look to you for guidance which you offer with gentleness and patience. I don't drive any more (have a disease which keeps me from having a license) and I've never even asked a question. When I look up things for my sweet hubby, they turn out to be duplicates because you're all so good at answering questions! Also, too often I forget to stop by to vote and occasionally edit. Yet, when I asked something of a high-rep user today, which I didn't really even have a right to ask, they responded with as much kindness as if I was an actual contributor! I guarantee you the same request wouldn't have been met with that elsewhere, even at my higher rep sites. I know that because I've done it!

You also use your meta for lively discussions in support of each other and the site. A post like this is just one example. Meta can be daunting, but when users check out this meta for the first time, they see the same spirit they find on the main site. It gives them courage to participate here too.

**Care for other communities**

You improve other sites too, obviously by asking and answering. Even at sites where you don't necessarily have a lot of interest, you still help by leaving kind comments, and voting.

I love [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), and spend most of my time there. We're an awesome community of people who care the way you do here. Questions are answered very fast, and both users and mods go out of their way to take time to help. Sadly though, we're a relatively low-voting site, but we've been greatly benefited by your presence there. I've watched the pattern change at least a little, especially voting for new users, which, again, translates to empowerment and a desire to hang around. We have quite a long way to go in that department, and you're helping us, and other sites as well.

I have to shout out to, and seriously thank, @Ducatikiller, who, under a different name, has almost singlehandedly raised the bar where votes are concerned. Check out all the tabs in the [voting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week) category of users.  In a very short time, he slam-bammed himself (I made that word up, but I like it) into 2nd for the year and 5th of all time! I used to stay easily in that spot, and now he keeps me on my toes, as does @Ppoggio. Compared to their level of rep and length of time and participation, they have very little to gain, so their help is altruistic and not self-serving. It's that way with all of you, and extends to many sites! (Voting is private, but I have a feeling one of you is helping me on all my sites, and has pushed me over 3k at Gardening. I'm humbled and very grateful!!!)

**Care for Stack Exchange**

When you care for something, you nurture it, and that's what you people do. You obviously believe that SE is the best place on the internet, and it shows in everything you do.

I'm blessed to call you my friends, and wish you great success as a graduated site.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: I should have known you'd stop by to say a word of two ... thanks for being here Sue!